# Javascript function parameter does not work

Tags: javascript

In my html form I have 4 file input fields.

```
<input type="file" id="one" name="Title_image1" onchange="check_extension(one)"/>
<input type="file" id="one2" name="Title_image2" onchange="check_extension(one3)"/>
<input type="file" id="one3" name="Title_image3" onchange="check_extension(one4)"/>
<input type="file" id="one4" name="Title_image4" onchange="check_extension(one5)"/>
```

I want to check file extension on inputs using javascript.

My function

```
function check_extension($field_id)
{
    var allowed = {'jpg': 1, 'png': 1};
    var fileinput = document.getElementById("$field_id");

    var y = fileinput.value.split(".");
    var ext = y[(y.length) - 1];
    ext = ext.toLowerCase();

    if (allowed[ext]) {
        document.chooseF.confirm.disabled = false;
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("This is an unsupported file type. Supported files are: jpg,png");
        document.chooseF.confirm.disabled = true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am using the same function for all the input fields with fieldid as parameter, but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

- `onchange="check_extension(one)"`

  Here `one` is the *Node* with the id "one", `one` is not the string `"one"`
- `document.getElementById("$field_id");`

  Even if `$field_id` is the id `"one"`, `"$field_id"` is a different string
  So `getElementById("$field_id")` will give you the node with id `"$field_id"`, not the node with id `"one"`.

### Fixes

```
onchange="check_extension('one')"
```

and

```
document.getElementById($field_id)
```

Also I discourage naming string variables with a leading `$`

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
<input type="file" id="one" name="Title_image1" onchange="check_extension(one)"/>
```

like so:

```
<input type="file" id="one" name="Title_image1" onchange="check_extension('one')"/>
```

Then change this:

```
function check_extension($field_id)
{
    var allowed = {'jpg': 1, 'png': 1};
    var fileinput = document.getElementById("$field_id");
....
```

like so:

```
function check_extension(field_id)
{
    var allowed = {'jpg': 1, 'png': 1};
    var fileinput = document.getElementById(field_id);
...
```